# Jquery Mobile SplitView for Iphone

Tags: jquery-mobile

How to make Jquery Mobile splitView (http://asyraf9.github.com/jquery-mobile/) works with Iphone,

I have tried changing min-width: 480px to smaller values in jquery.mobile.splitview.js, It dosen't work.

Any idea please?

I have taken an example from here, https://github.com/asyraf9/jquery-mobile/. It works fine when views from ipad and desktop,but not for my android and iphone devices.

Sample Code:

```
   <div data-role="panel" data-id="menu">
                <!-- Start of first page -->
                <div data-role="page" id="foo">

                    <div data-role="header">
                        <h1>Foo</h1>
                    </div><!-- /header -->

                    <div data-role="content">   
                        <p>I'm first in the source order so I'm shown as the page.</p>      
                        <p>View internal page called <a href="#bar">bar</a></p> 
                    </div><!-- /content -->

                    <div data-role="footer">
                        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
                    </div><!-- /footer -->
                </div><!-- /page -->
                <!-- other side panel pages here -->
            </div>
            <div data-role="panel" data-id="main">
                <!-- Start of second page -->
                <div data-role="page" id="bar">

                    <div data-role="header">
                        <h1>Bar</h1>
                    </div><!-- /header -->

                    <div data-role="content">   
                        <p>I'm first in the source order so I'm shown as the page.</p>      
                        <p><a href="#foo">Back to foo</a></p>   
                    </div><!-- /content -->

                    <div data-role="footer">
                        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
                    </div><!-- /footer -->
                </div><!-- /page -->
                <!-- other main panel pages here -->
            </div>
```

Comment: can you be more specific? do you have an example of your code that you can post?

Comment: Thanks, i have pasted the code.

Answer (score 0):

it wont work on iphone.. i tried it, even if u change the 480px thing it will become so slow that it will become unusable... 
 best way is to have 3 modes..

 splitview -> 2 columns

 popover -> the complementary view of splitview.. appears in ipad, with a popover menu

 none -> for normal phones. 

 the way u can do this is see the spltview code where it checks the condition of whether splitview can work or not. in its else it removes all the panel-html and leaves just the html of the menu panel. so this is your 3rd case. i suggest u do it this way only